# JavaScript canvas arc small angle ignore

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

For some reason when using small angle on arc function in canvas 2d context
It is not shown, even though angle is about 1deg, which is not even that small

How does one fix or overcomes this issue? (I'm using chrome, just in case)

Example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
//THIS IS SHOWN
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(200, 200);
c.arc(200, 200, 200, 0, 0.023);
c.lineTo(200, 200);
c.fill();
//THIS IS NOT SHOWN???
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(200, 200);
c.arc(200, 200, 200, Math.PI, Math.PI + 0.022); //change 22 to 23 to "fix"
c.lineTo(200, 200);
c.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: It seems to be a rounding problem. Fyi, it works with 0.0221. I tried it on a circle with a radius of 2500 and it's only visible > 0.022.

Comment: You should fill a bug report to chrome, doesn't occur on FF